# Azure Log Analytics Query returns 0 records Permission issue?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have CONTRIBUTOR permission Across the Entire Subscription and all components (verified thru Azure AD), but now when I try and query anything in Log Analytics (Monitor) and I am not able to view any records, I am able to query but everytime I get ZERO records.

My other colleague who has same role and also READER role on all Components is able view the records from same Log Analytics workspace.

Can someone help me on where can be the issue and why I am unable to get any records. As contributor role on Log Analytics should allow me to view all data but I cant see any records and anything I query in Log analytics returns me Zero record.

Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

I was querying thru the Resource Group (logs) instead  from the Log Analytics workspace, when I query from the RESOURCE GROUP --> Logs I get zero records and when I query from the Log Analytics workspace --> LOGS it works absolutely fine and returns all records.